# how do i resize tinymce after changin font-size?

Tags: resize, tinymce-4

Issue : when i have changed the font-size like 38pt, the text goes out of the editor.

I am using tinymce 4.0.

This is my script to load tinymce

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
        selector: "div#textareasDiv",
        theme: "modern",
        inline: true,
        plugins: [ "textcolor,table"],
        toolbar1: " bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | forecolor backcolor | fontselect |  fontsizeselect",
        image_advtab: true,
        menubar: false,
        fixed_toolbar_container: "#toolbarCon"


    });
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="textareasDiv"></div>
<div id="toolbarCon"></div>
```

and

```
<style>
#textareasDiv { padding:2px 5px;width:170px;height:80px;background:transparent;word-wrap: break-word; }
</style>
```

And I am trying to get its outerHeight so that i can make change on it :

```
setup : function(ed)
            {
                ed.on('change', function(e) 
                {
                    alert($(this.getContainer()).outerHeight());
                });
            }
```

But it gives me nothing.

How can i resize tinymce editor after changing font-size? and How can make this textareasDiv draggable?

[HERE IS THE FIDDLE](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/l0daab/7)

Comment: can you add a fiddle in www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @vignesh i have added fiddle please check..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing **`overflow`** in the `<textarea>` CSS definitions.

You may like to add it an set it to `auto`, which is the most common usage for it. Other options for **`overflow`** are: `scroll`, `overflow-x`, `overflow-y`, or `hidden`, depending on what result you are trying to achieve.

More about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp